# Xamarin Realm exit with no error but with no result

Tags: xamarin, realm

I don't know how to debug this behavior.

I trying to retrieve a row from my Realm database, but code just exit from the method when I query Realm.

```
    public User GetUser(int id)
    {
        User user = null;

        try
        {
            if (RealmInstance.All<User>().Where(a => a.Id == id).Any())
            {
                user = RealmInstance.All<User>().Where(a => a.Id == id).First();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return user;
    }
```

When I debug this method, I see debugger exit at this line `if(RealmInstance.All<User>().Where(a => a.Id == id).Any())` and no error is throw, it just go out without continue execution.

It's not the first time that I was front to this behavior and I don't know how to force Realm to get me some logs to see what appends.

edit 1 :

If split my code to this

```
var users = RealmInstance.All<User>();

var userFound = users.Where(a => a.Id == id);

//var userExist = userFound.Any(); //This cause the code to exit from method without exception
var userExist = userFound.Count() > 0; //This is OK sometimes, and other no. When it's work, it do not exit from method.

if (userExist)
{
   user = users.Where(a => a.Id == id).First();
}
```

But I still looking for a way to get exception from Realm

Comment: Are you using Windows? Is VS set to show all exceptions? All the packages are up to date?

Comment: MacOs, on Xamarin, VS show me all exceptions, I wondering if it's can be a Thread behavior. When I debug I have the feeling that app go out from the method, but in fact I suspect the thread to throw the exception and continu executing the parents method.